# android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: The camera device is in use already

Tags: android, android-camera

I am creating a simple flash app, but this doesnt seem to work as it is giving me an Exception of CameraAccessException which says camera is already in use.

This is my code for turning on flash.

```
private void turnFlashlightOff() {

        if (is_flash_on) {
            if (mCamera == null || p == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                try {
                    String cameraId;
                    camManager = (CameraManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
                    if (camManager != null) {
                        cameraId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                        camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);
                    }
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            } else {
                p = mCamera.getParameters();
                p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                is_flash_on = false;
                torchImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_lightbulb_outline_black_24dp);
            }

        }

    }
```

Any working solution would be fruitful.

Comment: which line throws the exception?

Comment: Getting similar exception. Did you end up with any fix ?

Comment: Nope. Guess, I still have the bug in that part and yet to find!